# How to show stdout logs in Heroku using Flask?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn, procfile

In my Python 3.7.1 app I'm using Flask and deploying it to Heroku and everything works fine, except for logging to the Heroku console. I've searched for answers, and thought I found some... but alas they don't end up printing out to the Heroku Log Console. When I run the app locally, using "py app.py" it shows up fine.

In my Procfile I have the following:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-level debug --log-file=-
```

In my app.py file, I have the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    formatter = logging.Formatter( "%(asctime)s | %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d | %(funcName)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s ")
    handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/SlackBotApp.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=5)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    app.logger.addHandler(handler)
    app.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    app.run()
```

I make a call to the logger like so:

```
app.logger.info("Url Requested: {}".format(url))
```

I have a feeling I need to make modifications to my Procfile, but I'm not sure what. Can anyone make any recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by adding the following to my app.py:

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
    app.logger.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
    app.logger.setLevel(gunicorn_logger.level)
```

And adjusting my Procfile to:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-level=debug
```

Thanks to https://medium.com/@trstringer/logging-flask-and-gunicorn-the-manageable-way-2e6f0b8beb2f for the answer