# Logging Flask Application in Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am trying to find a way to structure my code such that I can view logs in the production server hosted on Heroku.

Every tutorial I found seems to do logging like this:

[How to show stdout logs in Heroku using Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297215/how-to-show-stdout-logs-in-heroku-using-flask)

However, I am using the application factory pattern which utilizes `Blueprints`. As such here are some sample:

***main.py***

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

***app/_ _ *init* _ _.py***

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
...
db = SQLAlchemy() 
...
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    db.init_app(app)

    from .routes.demo_blueprint import demo_blueprint 
    ...
    # Register the routes to the Flask object
    app.register_blueprint(demo_blueprint) 
    ...
```

***app/routes/demo_blueprint.py***

```
from app import db
...
demo_blueprint = Blueprint('demo_blueprint', __name__)

@demo_blueprint.route('/demo', methods=['GET'])
...
```

In order to perform logging at the blueprint level, I would need to import `app` from `main.py`. However, this would cause an import error since `__init__.py` imports the blueprint before `app` is created. I was wondering if there were any work arounds for this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a simple fix. To access the application context in the `Blueprint`, just use `current_app`. Following the example:

[How to show stdout logs in Heroku using Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297215/how-to-show-stdout-logs-in-heroku-using-flask)

***main.py***

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

***app/_ _ *init* _ _.py***

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
...
db = SQLAlchemy() 
...
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    if __name__ != '__main__':
         gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
         app.logger.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
         app.logger.setLevel(gunicorn_logger.level)
    ...
    db.init_app(app)

    from .routes.demo_blueprint import demo_blueprint 
    ...
    # Register the routes to the Flask object
    app.register_blueprint(demo_blueprint) 
    ...
```

***app/routes/demo_blueprint.py***

```
from flask import ***current_user***
from app import db
...
demo_blueprint = Blueprint('demo_blueprint', __name__)

@demo_blueprint.route('/demo', methods=['GET'])
def demo():
    current_app.logger.debug('debug message: %s', 'test')
...
```